# Integrate carbon library in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-carbon

i'm having hard time trying to integrate the grate DateTime Library [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library with in my project in codeigniter 3
I tried this

```
$this->load->library('carbon');
```

and it's give me an error

```
not existing class
```

i think the problem is namespaces because carbon uses namespace carbon\carbon

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess if you still didn't find an answer for this problem, I think it's better for you to have a look at my answer bellow! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy steps:

1. Direct download: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php
2. Put Carbon.php at application/libraries
3. Create Mcarbon.php

   ```
   <?php

   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Carbon.php';

   use Carbon\Carbon;

   class Mcarbon extends Carbon
   {}
   ```
4. Put this in your Controller

   ```
   $this->load->library ( 'Mcarbon' );
   ```
5. Call Carbon method in any function. Example:

   ```
   <?php

   $dt =Mcarbon::createFromDate(2018,2,13,null);
   var_dump($dt->year);
   var_dump($dt->month);
   var_dump($dt->day);
   var_dump($dt->hour);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method for Codeigniter 3:

1. Install using Composer (I don't explain here how install Composer):

   - Open the terminal
   - Go to the root folder of your Codeigniter project and type:

     ```
     composer require nesbot/carbon ^2
     ```
   - It should install Carbon 2.x in the ***vendor/nestbot/Carbon*** folder
   - Remove the `ˆ2` to install the latest 1.x version (when writing this answer)
2. Update Codeigniter config file to autoload the component:

   - Open ***application/config/config.php*** and change:

     ```
     $config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
     ```

     to:

     ```
     $config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'/vendor/autoload.php';
     ```
3. Create a Codeigniter library for Carbon:

   - Create the ***application/libraries/Carbon_lib.php*** file:

   ```
   <?php

   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   use Carbon\Carbon;

   public function __construct($time = null, $tz = null) {

     parent::__construct($time, $tz);

   }
   ```
4. Load the library in your controller, model...:

   ```
   $this->load->library('carbon_lib');
   ```
5. Use the library as you would with Carbon:

   ```
   $carbon = $this->carbon_lib;
   $carbon->addDay();
   //Get the SQL date and date/time format
   $carbon->toDateString();
   $carbon->toDateTimeString();
   //And to create an immutable object
   $carbonImmutable = $this->carbon_lib->toImmutable();
   ...
   ```

See [Carbon website](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps for Codeigniter 3:

1. Install carbon via composer

   composer require nesbot/carbon
2. Update index.php, Add this line

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
3. In your controller add this line at the top.

   use Carbon\Carbon;

Now you can use carbon functionalities.
example:

```
Carbon::now();
```